# How to play transparent .MOV files in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

so I have a .MOV file that has a transparent background (I think it means it has a alpha channel?). I want to play it back using WPF, but the MediaElement control is not able to play .MOV files natively. I tried using this [library](https://unosquare.github.io/ffmediaelement/) to play the file but it didn't work.

Is there any library that is able to play these types of files and also maybe play other files too like a MP4?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, were you able to find a library?